# How can I align bootstrap 3 navbar verically

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Maybe it looks simple but it became a problem for me:
I need logo and all of the `li a` elements to be aligned to bottom and on one line, padding, margin?

```
   <!-- Fixed navbar -->
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img class="logo" alt=" logo" src="Logo.png" height="35" width="50" >
      <span class="logo-text">logo text</span>  
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right ">
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>            
      </ul>

    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.navbar-brand` is 100% height within the navbar, however it's padded out so that any text is middle aligned. When I need to stick an image in that element, or any other navbar elements for that matter, I use a CSS `background-image` like so:

```
.navbar-brand {
    width: 170px; /* Your image width */
    background: url(../img/logo.png) center bottom no-repeat;
}
```

This gives you good control over the image position.